# Best way to validate multiple fields in JAVA?

Tags: java, validation

Hi I have many fields that I need to validate for the **null** and empty i.e **""**

If I have to validate 5 strings then here is the code.

```
string.equals("") || string1.equals("") || string2.equals("") || string3.equals("") || string4.equals("")
 || 
string.equals(null) || string1.equals(null) || string2.equals(null) || string3.equals(null) || string4.equals(null)
```

then it looks odd. If there are about 10 strings then more ugly.

Please tell me the best practice to do it.

Comment: 10 question has been asked by you, none of answer is worthy to you?.

Comment: Accept some of your answers, it's the green tick on the left by the up and down arrows.

Comment: you post "worthy" comment as you yourself worthy for me to accept any answer. :) Sure I am going to do it.

Comment: you can only mark one answer as 'green tick' , you removed it ;-)

Comment: @Blundell oh Sorry i don't know about "one answer" limitation. Anyhow I make your answer up(useful). if my question is useful or clear to you in any case then you can give it an up. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should write a method such as below;;

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String... strArr) {
       for (String st : strArr) {
            if  (st==null || st.equals(""))
               return true;

       } 
       return false;
}



boolean result = isNullOrEmpty(string1,strin2,string3,string4,string5);
```

Comment: +1: With varargs, you don't need the `new String[] {` ;)  Perhaps `isNullOrEmpty` is better

Comment: @Peter Lawrew, applied recommended changes. :)

Comment: Just need to add a ')' to the if statement. ;)

Answer (score 2):

At least you can optimize:

```
string1.equals("") || string1.equals(null)
```

to

```
StringUtils.isBlank(string1);
```

StringUtils: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: please tell me about StringUtils. is this a system class or any framework class?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about best practice, but you could tidy up your code:

```
String[] inputs = new String[5];
inputs[0] = "whatever";

private boolean stringValidate(String[] inputs){
      for(int i=0; i < inputs.size(); i++){
           String currentString = inputs[i];
           if(currentString == null || currentString.equals(""){
               return false; // validation failed
           }
      }
      return true; // Validation passed
}
```

You could probably use a List make it even nicer.

*EDIT*

Yes as peter says using VarArgs *(which I should do more often!)*:

```
private boolean stringValidate(String... inputs) {
      for (String currentString  : inputs) {
          if(currentString == null || currentString.equals(""){
               return false; // validation failed
           }
      }
      return true; // Validation passed
   }
```

Called like this:

```
stringValidate("foo", "bar", "bar");
```

Comment: Using varargs and the foreach loop would make this nicer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`string.equals(null)` would never work, since if string was null, you'd get an NPE. I guess you mean `string == null`.

Nevertheless, you could use apache commons lang's `StringUtils` which would reduce the check to `StringUtils.isEmpty(string) || ...`

Answer (score 1):

Create a validate method to handle each one.

```
private boolean isValid(String parameter){
if (parameter == null || parameter.isEmpty()) return false;
return true;
}
```

Then you can call this method for each of your strings. Note that if you're using an earlier version of java than 1.6, you can replace the `isEmpty()` method with `!parameter.equals("")`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly string.equals(null) is never true. is string is null this will throw a NullPointerException.

You can use `string == null || string.equals("")`

The problem you have is that you have many fields/variables which you want to treat in a generic fashion but you have different names.  An alternative is to use an array or List

```
String[] strings = { .... }
boolean notAllSet = false;
for(String s: strings)
   notAllSet |= s==null || s.equals("");
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, a best practice is to do

```
 "FOO".equals(myString)
```

instead.  This reduces the chance of NPEs and makes it clearer that no mutation is going on.  For a discussion of this, see [here](http://www.moserware.com/2008/01/constants-on-left-are-better-but-this.html).

Also, if you really have a collection of strings to compare to, you probably want

```
 final Set<String> validStrings = ...

 boolean validate(final String foo) {
    return foo!=null && validStrings.contains(foo);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're handling a lot of variables of the same type, you can manage them in a structure, such as an ArrayList, then create a method to do the work for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<String> hold = new ArrayList<String>();
    hold.add(string);
    hold.add(string1);
    hold.add(string2);
    hold.add(string3);
    hold.add(string4);

    if( validate(hold) )
        System.out.println("No blanks, no nulls");
}

public boolean validate(ArrayList<String> hold){
     for( int x = 0; x < hold.size(); x++ ){
          if( hold.get(x).equals("") || hold.get(x).equals(null) )
                return false;
     }

     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is very old, but I find `StringUtils` to be more suited for this.

`StringUtils.isAnyEmpty(String... args)`

Or

`StringUtils.isAnyBlank(String... args)`

Hope this helps someone!

Docs, [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)